# What's new in Okami HD compared to the original?

Tags: version-differences, okami, okami-hd

So after hunting around the various review sites and message boards, I still have one question about this game:  Aside from the updated graphics, is there anything new in this version of the game?

I've played the Wii version, as well as the Okamiden game for the DS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing new in Okami HD is the updated graphics.

Here you can see a comparison of the two, starting at around the two minute mark.

[Okami SD vs Okami HD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=evRYEFzAY8w#!)

Answer (score 4):

According to [this webpage](http://okami.wikia.com/wiki/%C5%8Ckami), in addition to the improved graphics (1080p, widescreen), the new features compared to the original are:

- a [trophy/achievement system](http://okami.wikia.com/wiki/%C5%8Ckami_HD%27s_achievements)
- Playstation Move Controller support

According to the same webpage, the (American) Wii version omitted the original ending credits movie, which was restored for the PS3 "HD" version, so if you've only played the Wii version, that will be new to you, too.